# How to delete remaining files after package deinstalation? (wine)

Tags: wine

Im struggling with the problem that makes me unable to install wine.
Whenever Im trying to install it, the information about broken packages appears, however, as I type in:
`$ dpkg -l | grep wine`

A severeal wine files appear: (aaandd I will just give screenshoot of it, dont ask why)[Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDGon.png)

And, since they are system files, I cant just delete them just by left-clicking, and move to trash bin

So im asking: is there a simple way to delete this files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Did this already, files still there.

Comment: @JuliuszBarnat - What was the output from that command?

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get purge wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'wine' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  p7zip wine-development wine64-development winetricks
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: sudo apt-get install wine1.8

Comment: @JuliuszBarnat - See my edited answer

Comment: you meant autoremove, not autoreomve?

Comment: @JuliuszBarnat Ooops :D, yes, I fixed the typo :)

Comment: yeaaa, it worked, but it didnt actually solved my problem with wine installation. Thanks for help, thought.